# Migrating SQL table to in memory using MOA

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to migrate an SQL table to in-memory.

I am using the 'Memory Optimization Advisor' tool.

A new table is being created with same name as before "EVENTS". I have Java code that is querying this table. Now all the queries are not working and nothing is presented in the GUI.

Can anyone suggest what the problem might be?

Comment: Let's see the Java code and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Hi @RickJames apparently it had to do with me forgetting to check an option in the MOA and then everything works great.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the answer is that using MOA you have to check the option marked here in purpule and this migrates all the data to the memory optimized table.

[image]